# Imaginary Number Inequalities

Tags: complex-numbers

I've been thinking about lately complex numbers and inequalities, and after establishing there is no way to order all complex numbers I thought can you order imaginary numbers?

I started by questioning is $i>-i$ or $-i> i$.

Assume $i>-i$, then
$$ii>-ii = i^2>-i^2$$
But $i^2 = -1$, so $-1>1$. Which is false.

Assume then $-i>i$, then
$$-ii>ii = -i^2>i^2$$
But $i^2 = -1$, so $1>-1$. Which is true.

Does this mean that $-i>i$ or have I missed something? Does it then mean that if $a>b$, then $-ai > bi$?

Thanks

Comment: There is no good and natural way to put an order on the complex numbers. This is one of the tradeoffs: we gain algebraic closedness, but lose the ordering.

Comment: No we cannot compare complex numbers like real ones .

Comment: I'm not asking to compare complex numbers, rather imaginary ones

Comment: You *can* order complex numbers to satisfy *some* ordering properties, but you *can't* order them to satisfy *all*.  So mathematician say there is no "natural" order on the complex.

Comment: Basically if there is a complete order $x^2 \ge 0$ always.  That can't happen if $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: You can order the imaginary numbers but the order can't hold over multiplication which brings in the reals and complex numbers.

Comment: An ordered *field* has the additional properties if y > z then x + y > x + z for all x, and if x > 0 and y > z then xy > xz.  Those two properties are absolutely incompatible with complex numbers.

Comment: The definition of an order is: i) one and only one of the following is always true; x < y, y < x, or x = y and ii) if x < y and y < z then x < z.  That's all.  Obviously we can order the imaginary numbers.  We can order the complex numbers.  We can order practically any set.  An ordered *field* has the two conditions I listed in a previous cooment.  Thus can not be applied to imaginary numbers.  Although the can to the reals and the rationals.

Comment: Also note:  you claim you know you can not order complex numbers and are wondering about strictly imaginary.  But if so you can't do multiplication as ii is *not* imaginary.

Answer (score 1):

If you define an order on the purely imaginary numbers by $-ai>bi\iff a>b$, you may start running into problems when multiplying both sides of the inequality by $i$ or $-i$ so that $<$ or $>$ would not have properties one would expect.  Take for example, $3i>-4i$ because $-3>-4$.  If you multiply both sides by $i$ or $-i$, you will see that $>$ will not behave the same way as it would if you multiplied both sides of $-3i>2i$ (because $3>2$) by $i$ or $-i$.

Answer (score 1):

The complex numbers are simply not an ordered *field* and there is no way to make them one.

You can define orders that satisfy some of the properties but you can't define an order that satisfies all.

For example if you define a+bi < c + di if a < b or a=b and c < d, then that satisfies that x < y,x=y,y < x are always the one mutually exclusive possibilities, and that if x < y and y < z, then x < z.

That's two it satisfies, but here is one it doesn't.

It doesn't satisfy the requirement if x > 0 and y > 0 then xy > 0.

In fact one of the requirements of an ordered field is that if x is isn't 0, then $x^2 > 0$.  (Do you want me to explain why?)

This means $i^2 =-1 > 0$ and $1^2=1 > 0$.  This is impossible as another requirement is: if x > 0, then -x < 0.  (Do you want me to explain why?)

Comment: Yes please why does $x^2 > 0$ a property for it be ordered?